# How yo use arrayFilters with mongoose 5.x.x?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967418/multiple-arrays-of-objects-inside-array-of-objects-in-mongodb) couple of days ago about updating arrays in nested arrays of objects. Right now MongoDB 3.6 officially supports it via `arrayFilters` feature.

Is it implemented in Mongoose 5.x.x? What's the syntax? Which method should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually here is an example of `findOneAndUpdate` command:

```
Company.findOneAndUpdate(
  {'companyId': parseInt(req.params.companyId)},
  {$pull: {'companyDivisions.$[element].divisionDepartments': {'departmentId': parseInt(req.params.departmentId)}}},
  {arrayFilters: [{'element.divisionId': parseInt(req.params.divisionId)}]},
  (err) => {
    if (err) res.status(400).json(err)
    res.status(200).json({success: true, message: 'this worked without errors!'})
  }
)
```

I had two problems:

1) I tried to add a `test` field which wasn't represented in my schema.

2) I completely forgot to `parseInt` the hell out of my params, because in my schema these are numbers.

Thank you everybody. :D

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$[element.divisionId]`? Or just `'element'` in your arrayFilters object? It is my understanding that those identifiers should match?