# Update object in nested array MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, nested, mongodb-query

I'm trying to update some of the value inside nested arrays using `id` as shown below:-

Nested array:-

```
let people = [
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "Person 1",
        "pets": [
            {
                "_id": 1,
                "name": "Tom",
                "category": "cat",
                "favFood": [
                    {
                        "_id": 1,
                        "name": "steamed fish", // this will be updated
                        "gred": "A" // this will be updated
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": 2, 
                        "name": "fried fish",
                        "gred": "B"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": 2,
                "name": "Jerry",
                "category": "mouse",
                "favFood": [
                    {
                        "_id": 1,
                        "name": "cheese",
                        "gred": "C"
                    }
                ] 
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Right now I've something like this:-

```
People.updateOne(
    { "$set": { "pets.$[petID].favFood.$[favFoodID].name" : "bbq fish", 
                "pets.$[petID].favFood.$[favFoodID].gred" : "A+" }             
    },
    {
      multi: true,
      arrayFilters: [ 
          { "petID._id": 1 }, // pet with id of '1'
          { "favFoodID._id": 1 } // favFood with id of '1'
        ]
    },
    (err, success) => {
        if(err) res.json({ message: `Unsuccessful!`, report: err })
        else res.json({ message: `Successful!`, report: success })
    }
)
```

But, unfortunately I got **error** of `"message": "\"_id\" is not allowed"`. And I don't know which `_id` that was not allowed or cause of the error.

What I would want is to alter or update as following:-

```
let people = [
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "Person 1",
        "pets": [
            {
                "_id": 1,
                "name": "Tom",
                "category": "cat",
                "favFood": [
                    {
                        "_id": 1,
                        "name": "bbq fish", // this value was updated
                        "gred": "A+" // this value was updated
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": 2, 
                        "name": "fried fish",
                        "gred": "B"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": 2,
                "name": "Jerry",
                "category": "mouse",
                "favFood": [
                    {
                        "_id": 1,
                        "name": "cheese",
                        "gred": "C"
                    }
                ] 
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Can anyone direct me on which part on my codes above causing the error?

**Adjusted** `updateOne`:-

```
People.updateOne(
    { "_id": 1,
      "pets._id": 1,
      "favFood._id": 1 
    },
    { $set: { "pets.favFood.$$.name" : "bbq fish", 
              "pets.favFood.$$.gred" : "A+", } 
    },
    (err, success) => {
        if(err) res.json({ message: `Unsuccessful!`, report: err })
        else res.json({ message: `Successful!`, report: success })
    }
)
```

It's able to return `Successful!`. But the values in database **does not change**. From here, how can I tweak my code?

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: The use of `multi: true` doesn't  belong in the `collection#updateOne` method.

Comment: @thammada.ts I'm using Mongoose with Nodejs. Version of Mongoose is `5.9.20`

Comment: @prasad_ then should not use `multi:true`? Cause it still returns the same error.

Comment: The syntax is still not correct. The `updateOne`'s first parameter must be a _query.filter_; your code doesn't have any. Please follow the syntax from the following link: [updateOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateOne) method of Mongoose.

Comment: @prasad_ I've adjusted the code as what being implemented here at this [link](https://www.nodechef.com/docs/cloud-search/updates-documents-nested-in-arrays). Please refer above.

Comment: The query filter is not correct.  The _field path_ to the `"favFood._id": 1` is not correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217890/discussion-between-lala-and-prasad).

Comment: This should solve: [How to use arrayFIlters with Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095532/how-yo-use-arrayfilters-with-mongoose-5-x-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:-

**Working Code** for `updateOne`:-

```
People.updateOne(
    {},
    { "$set": { "pets.$[petID].favFood.$[favFoodID].name" : "bbq fish", 
                "pets.$[petID].favFood.$[favFoodID].gred" : "A+" 
              } 
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [ 
          { "petID._id": 1 },
          { "favFood._id": 1 }
        ]
    },
    (err, success) => {
        if(err) res.json({ message: `Unsuccessful!`, report: err })
        else res.json({ message: `Successful!`, report: success })
    }
)
```